# create destination path for shutil.copy files

Tags: python

If a path such as `b/c/` does not exist in `./a/b/c` , `shutil.copy("./blah.txt", "./a/b/c/blah.txt")` will complain that the destination does not exist. What is the best way to create both the destination path and copy the file to this path?

Answer (score 136):

To summarize info from the given answers and comments:

**For python 3.2+**:

[`os.makedirs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.makedirs) before [`copy`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) with `exist_ok=True`:

```
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_fpath), exist_ok=True)
shutil.copy(src_fpath, dest_fpath)
```

**For python < 3.2:**

`os.makedirs` after catching the `IOError` and try copying again:

```
try:
    shutil.copy(src_fpath, dest_fpath)
except IOError as io_err:
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest_fpath))
    shutil.copy(src_fpath, dest_fpath)
```

Although you could be more explicit about checking `errno` and/or checking if path `exists` before `makedirs`, IMHO these snippets strike a nice balance between simplicity and functionality.

Comment: weird that copying files and creating directories are in two different modules.

Answer (score 42):

Use `os.makedirs` to create the directory tree.

Comment: Note that the `exists_ok` option is only present in Python 3.2+

Comment: It's `exist_ok`, not `exists_ok`

Answer (score 31):

I use something similar to this to check if the directory exists before doing things with it.

```
if not os.path.exists('a/b/c/'):
    os.mkdir('a/b/c')
```

Comment: As far as I know, this won't work in Python 2.7:
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './a/b/c'

Comment: I prefer to use `os.makedirs` instead, which would create parent directories if they don't exist.

Comment: Be aware that this suffers from a race condition (if someone else or another thread create the directory between the check and calling `makedirs`). Better to call `os.makedirs` and catch the exception if the folder exist. Check SoF for directory creation.

Answer (score 22):

This is the [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp) way, which avoids races and unneeded syscalls:

```
import errno
import os
import shutil

src = "./blah.txt"
dest = "./a/b/c/blah.txt"
# with open(src, 'w'): pass # create the src file
try:
    shutil.copy(src, dest)
except IOError as e:
    # ENOENT(2): file does not exist, raised also on missing dest parent dir
    if e.errno != errno.ENOENT:
        raise
    # try creating parent directories
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(dest))
    shutil.copy(src, dest)
```

Comment: There is still a race if `dest` dir is created after the call to `shutil.copy` but before the call to `os.makedirs`.

Answer (score 11):

For 3.4/3.5+ you can use [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.mkdir):

> Path.mkdir(mode=0o777, parents=False, exist_ok=False)

---

So if there might be multiple directories to create and if they might already exist:

```
pathlib.Path(dst).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 9):

How about I use split to get the dir out of the path

```
dir_name, _ = os.path.split("./a/b/c/blah.txt")
```

then

```
os.makedirs(dir_name,exist_ok=True)
```

and finally

```
shutil.copy("./blah.txt", "./a/b/c/blah.txt")
```

Comment: Note that if the `dir_name` contains subdirectories that don't exist you'll want to adjust the code to `os.makedirs(dir_name + '/',exist_ok=True)`

Answer (score 1):

My five cents there would be is the next approach:

```
# Absolute destination path.
dst_path = '/a/b/c/blah.txt'
origin_path = './blah.txt'
not os.path.exists(dst_path) or os.makedirs(dst_path)
shutil.copy(origin_path, dst_path)
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the other answers are for older versions of Python, although they may still work, you can handle errors a lot better with newer Pythons.

If you are using **Python 3.3 or newer**, we can catch `FileNotFoundError` instead of `IOError`. We also want to differentiate between the destination path not existing ***and the source path not existing***. We want to swallow the former exception, but not the latter.

Finally, beware that `os.makedirs()` recursively creates missing directories one at a time--meaning that it is not an atomic operation. You may witness unexpected behavior if you have multiple threads or processes that might try to create the same directory tree at the same time.

```py
def copy_path(*, src, dst, dir_mode=0o777, follow_symlinks: bool = True):
    """
    Copy a source filesystem path to a destination path, creating parent
    directories if they don't exist.

    Args:
        src: The source filesystem path to copy. This must exist on the
            filesystem.

        dst: The destination to copy to. If the parent directories for this
            path do not exist, we will create them.

        dir_mode: The Unix permissions to set for any newly created
            directories.

        follow_symlinks: Whether to follow symlinks during the copy.

    Returns:
        Returns the destination path.
    """
    try:
        return shutil.copy2(src=src, dst=dst, follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks)
    except FileNotFoundError as exc:
        if exc.filename == dst and exc.filename2 is None:
            parent = os.path.dirname(dst)
            os.makedirs(name=parent, mode=dir_mode, exist_ok=True)
            return shutil.copy2(
                src=src,
                dst=dst,
                follow_symlinks=follow_symlinks,
            )
        raise
```