# Renaming a file one another disk

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

My python script is on partition D and I want to rename files in folders on partition E:

I can't move the folder/files to D, because of limited space.

```
path= "E:\\A" 

for f in os.listdir(path):

    f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)

    empty, f_number, f_title = (f_name.split('_'))
    f_title = f_title.strip()

    if len(f_number) == 2:
        f_number = '0' + f_number

   f_filename = '_{}_{}{}'.format(f_number, f_title, f_ext)
   file = os.path.join(path, f)
   os.rename(file, f_filename)
```

I get the error:

> [WinError 17] The system cannot move the file to a different disk
>   drive:

I found an answer here to use shutils. So I tried:

```
 src = os.path.join(path, f)  
 path2 = "E:\\A2"   
 dst = os.path.join(path2, f_filename)    
 shutil.move(src, dst)
```

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: "E:\A2\filename"

That's strange because I'm taking the file from A and move it to A2 with a new filename, so clearly doesn't exist on A2.

Comment: What are the values of `file` and `f_filename` showing as before you call `os.rename(file, f_filename)` ?

Comment: file is the original name of the file and f_file_name is the new name; If I'm on the same partition is working properlly;

Comment: Well yes.... but your error would indicate you weren't issuing the rename specifying the E drive... that's why I was asking you to check what the values are for those... there's nothing stopping a rename command that equates to `rename E:\test.txt E:\test2.txt`... (even if you're on C or D or whatever)

Comment: you are correct, I attached the path to initial file, but not to the f_filename, considering the the path is already known, and only filename is changed

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the error message, I suspect the problem is that you are attempting to move those files into the `"A2"` directory before that directory is created. If `A2` doesn't exist yet, you can create it using `os.mkdir`.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793789/create-destination-path-for-shutil-copy-files) for more details about that.