# Copy files using python with complete folder structure

Tags: python, windows-10

I am switching my SSD with a better one in a few days and I have a bunch of data stored on it that I might regret if deleted. The only type of files I need are PDF files, docx files, txt files and other things.
So, I wrote a script to locate those files using python.

```
# to copy all of my documents into another location.
import sys
import os
import time
import pathlib
import json


filePath=["D:\\", "C:\\Users"]
# ext=['mkv','docx','doc','pdf','mp4','zip',]
fileExt=["**\*.docx","**\*.doc","**\*.pdf"]
fileList={}
for each_drive in filePath:
    fileList[each_drive]={}
    for each_type in fileExt:
        fileList[each_drive][each_type]=list(pathlib.Path(each_drive).glob(each_type))

file1 = open('test.txt', 'w')
for each in fileList.values():
    for each2 in each.values():
        for entry in each2:
            print(entry)
            file1.writelines(str(str(entry)+ "\n"))


file1.close()
```

This script just locates the file with formats matching the FileExt list and writes out those locations to test.txt file.
Now I need to transfer these files while keeping the exact directory structure.
For example, If there is a file as

```
C:\Users\<MyUser>\AppData\Local\Files\S0\1\Attachments\hpe[4].docx
```

The script should copy the entire directory structure as

```
<BackupDrive>:\<BackupFolderName>\C\Users\<MyUser>\AppData\Local\Files\S0\1\Attachments\hpe[4].docx
```

How do I copy using this exact structure.
TLDR: Need to copy files while keeping the directory structure as is using Python
P.S. I am using Windows, with Python 3.8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004073/how-can-i-create-directories-recursively

Comment: I thank what you shoud do is, to extract all the paths (without file) change the base from C: to BachupDrive: and then use `makedirs` to create the paths. It does so recursively as shown in above post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For each line in your file list, do the following:

```
for filePath in fileList:
    destination = .join(['<BackupDrive>:\<BackupFolderName>', filePath[2:]])
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filePath), exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy(filePath , destination)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are able to write data to a file, I am assuming you also know how to read data from that file. Then for each line (say call it `source` in that file, use `shutil.copyfile(source, dest)`.

You can create the `dest` string by manipulating `source`:

```
# remove 'C:'
str_split = source[2:]

# add backup drive and folder
dest = ''.join(['<BackupDrive>:\<BackupFolderName>', str_split])
```

As mentioned in the comments, the destination path will not be created automatically, but can be handled like explained here: [create destination path for shutil.copy files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793789/create-destination-path-for-shutil-copy-files)

Comment: This does not create the folders on the way if I am correct, does it?

Comment: Nope. It does not. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004073/how-can-i-create-directories-recursively
Following this link and this answer, I  need to first create destination directories then move these files?

Comment: I would include this to the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793789/create-destination-path-for-shutil-copy-files

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Emmo and @FloLie for their Answers. I just had to use the os.makedirs() function with the exist_ok flag set to true for each file in the list.

This is the code placed immediately after the code in the question.

```
#######################################
# create destination directory
file1=open ('test.txt', 'r')
text= file1.readlines()
# print(text)
for each in text:
    each=each[:-1]
    destination="BackupDIR-"+each[0]+each[2:]
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination), exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy(each,destination)
```

This makes the entire code look like:

```
# to copy all of my documents into another location.
import os
import time
import pathlib
import json
import shutil


filePath=["D:\\", "C:\\Users"]
# ext=['mkv','docx','doc','pdf','mp4','zip',]
fileExt=["**\*.docx","**\*.doc","**\*.pdf"]
fileList={}
for each_drive in filePath:
    fileList[each_drive]={}
    for each_type in fileExt:
        fileList[each_drive][each_type]=list(pathlib.Path(each_drive).glob(each_type))

file1 = open('test.txt', 'w')
for each in fileList.values():
    for each2 in each.values():
        for entry in each2:
            print(entry)
            file1.writelines(str(str(entry)+ "\n"))
file1.close()

#######################################
# create destination directory
file1=open ('test.txt', 'r')
text= file1.readlines()
# print(text)
for each in text:
    each=each[:-1]
    destination="BackupDIR-"+each[0]+each[2:]
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(destination), exist_ok=True)
    shutil.copy(each,destination)
```

P.S. This answer is only here for people like me who cant make sense of little snippets out of context sometimes