# Move files from location to another location using python

Tags: python, file-handling

How do I copy files inside a directory  using python.All my AB.jpg should be copied to  one folder and BC.jpg files to one more folder of  by sub scripting the file with it's date from the file path). My path's created are dynamic based on the timestamps.

My local directory paths are in the below format:

```
directory : /tmp/hash/inputsrc/20201229/....../AB.jpg
            /tmp/hash/inputsrc/20201228/....../BC.jpg
            /tmp/hash/inputsrc/20201229/....../AB.jpg
            /tmp/hash/inputsrc/20201228/....../BC.jpg
Expected output:
           /newfolder/AB_20201229.jpg
           /newfolder/AB_20201228.jpg
           /newfolder/BC_20201229.jpg
           /newfolder/BC_20201228.jpg
```

Comment: Do you want to copy (as stated in the question) or move (as stated in the title)?

Comment: Look at `shutils`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793789/create-destination-path-for-shutil-copy-files

Comment: I want to organise / move files @WilliamPursell

Comment: Also how do I add timestamp from the path that's show in my input to the filename as I can distinguish them only on timestamps @MaNKuR